# Mysql data retrieve in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to execute a simple mySQL query in a php page, and I keep getting this error :
"Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in..."
even though the query returns a result in mysql workbench.
This is my code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","eshkol");
// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $sql1="SET Names utf8";

 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE idStudent=2");
    $r = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    echo $r["idStudent"];



if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql1))
  {
  die('Error hebrew: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "success";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions.

```
$sql = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM student WHERE idStudent=2");
$r = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
```

should be

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM student WHERE idStudent=2");
$r = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
```

What's interesting is you're using them just below that code:

```
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql1))
  {
  die('Error hebrew: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
```

You probably want to combine the two to clean up your code:

```
$sql = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM student WHERE idStudent=2");
if (!$sql) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
$r = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
```

Comment: Thank, That works, but I'm still getting this error "Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in..."

Comment: Make sure the query you provide is an actual query and not something else

Comment: It's an actual query, I don't follow you, @JohnConde

Comment: Apparently it is not a string but some sort of object. Do a _var_dump()` on that variable to inspect it closer.

Comment: I'm questioning this `$sql1="SET Names utf8";` in conjunction with `if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql1))` --- Is that "legal"?